# How to iterate through this nested json array with python

Tags: python, json, api, jira, jira-rest-api

So I made an API call to JIRA to get the list of all the issues. It returns something like this:

```
{
 issues: [
  {
    fields: {
         description: 
         summary: 
         creator:
         reporter:
         priority:
       }
     }
   ]
```

and I'm trying to get to what's inside `fields`. 
Here's what I have:

`response =  requests.get(url + '/search?jql=resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20order%20by%20priority%20DESC,updated%20DESC', auth=auth).json()`

and then :

`response['issues']` works. But I can't find a way to access `fields` and then the elements inside it. I thought about iterating through but not sure if there's a simpler solution.

My understanding is that response[issues] is a list and I know how to access each element of it `response[issues][0]` but how to access the object nested inside the list? (still researching on it -- might find an answer)

Comment: `response[issues][0][fields]`

Comment: @Gerrat I was so close!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at your json it's an array to a hash or list to dict. To get  fields you'd just call the first array element and the key.

`response[issues][0][fields]`